Expo - react-native-cloud-store upload file into Icloud
I want to upload a file to iCloud Drive to make it public. I can already write files to the directory, but I want to make that file shareable. In the documentation I should use the setUbiquitous function to do so. However, whenever I use these functions (I've tried upload and getUrlForPublishingUbiquitousItem), I get errors like this:
{
code: ERR_SET_UB,
message: "The file "filename.txt" couldn't be opened",
domain: "",
userInfo: {},
nativeStackIOS: ["0AppName0x00000000000102d4938RCTJSErrorFromCodeMessageAndNSError + 112", ""
...
}
PS: I can open file from the finder
import {
  defaultICloudContainerPath,
  isICloudAvailable,
  readDir,
  writeFile,
  setUbiquitous,
  stat,
} from "react-native-cloud-store";


  try {
      setIsCreating(true);

      const [date, details] = new Date().toISOString().split("T");

      const fileName = `filename.txt`;

      const finalPath = currPath
        ? `${defaultICloudContainerPath}${currPath}/${fileName}`
        : `${defaultICloudContainerPath}/${fileName}`;

      await writeFile(finalPath, "Hello world");
      await setUbiquitous(true, finalPath, "/"); // error on this line
      setFiles([...files, shorterPath(finalPath)]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    } finally {
      setIsCreating(false);
    }

Should work but gives me an error.
